# open source DNS management

Tags: linux, open-source, web-services, dns

I'm looking for an DNS management solution.  Features I'd like:

- add and remove [zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone)
- add, edit, or remove records in zones
- intuitive web UI
- automatic lint before commit
- limit which users can edit which zones

Technical requirements:

- open source or free software license
- runs on Linux
- compatible with BIND
- REST API
- preferably written in Perl, JavaScript or Python (no Java, Ruby or PHP)

My searches have not led to anything recent on this topic.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_management_software#DNS_management_software_comparison) has the most authoritative list of options but it includes "mysqlBind" which seems to have evaporated and other choices that are over a decade old.

At this point [nictool](http://www.nictool.com/) seems to be the clear winner, but it is missing the REST API and I'm not sure how active the community is.  Is there a better choice at this time?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "DNS Management Solution" and "zones."

Comment: @Menasheh: then you should probably not provide an answer ;-) DNS is the domain name system, which provides you the addresses in the internet so you can type it in your browser

Comment: @ThomasWeller Actually DNS stands for domain name *service,* and I would not have termed that a DNS "management solution."  But if you could define "zones" as they pertain to DNS, that would help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone was linked yesterday for the word "zone" above to provide context for people not familiar with DNS terminology.

Comment: So by DNS management solution, you mean DNS server?

Comment: No.  If you click on the link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_management_software#DNS_management_software_comparison you can see examples.

Comment: @Menasheh: Why do you think it stands for "Service"? Wikipedia also says system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Comment: You're right.  both are valid in theory, but system is the applicable one.  Yesterday google listed a bunch including both but I can't recreate that now.

Answer (score 1):

I came across [**AtomiaDNS**](http://atomiadns.com/) lately and it may be worth a look. Provides all requested features. An API is also available, even if it's not a pure REST API.

Comment: That looks great.  It seems to meet all of the requirements.  SOAP is close enough for me to a good API.  I'll give it a shot when I get a chance.

Comment: Did you ever get AtomiaDNS running? I seem to be running into a variety of issues with the documentation being incomplete and out of date. If you chose a different solution can you share which DNS management tool you use?

Comment: Never tried to setup the software. But seems that you are not the only one. Maybe hook into [this issue report](https://github.com/atomia/atomiadns/issues/35)?